# Creating Figures in GEF eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-gef

In GEF I want to create figure that is rhombus in shape and also I want to add label to each of the vertex of the figure with some text for each vertex.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Implement a figure that is composed of 5 elements: four labels and a rhombus figure. Place each figure inside the parent figure using standard draw2d constrants.
The rhombus figure itself is easy to implement, by extending the `Shape` class. You can see [how I did this](http://www.vainolo.com/2011/07/20/extending-org-eclipse-draw2d-shape-a-short-experience/) for a triangle. 
If you need more in-depth knowledge of draw2d, check out [this tutorial](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-Draw2d/GEF-Draw2d.html).